# Casting java.sql.Connection to Oracle Connection

Tags: java, oracle, connection, wildfly-10

I have a java application where I call Oracle procedure and passing Oracle array as parameter. My application is EAR.

Everything worked correctly on Java 7 and Jboss 7, but when we upgraded to Java 8 and Wildfly 10 we got this error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException:
 org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7 cannot be cast
 to org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection
```

After some research I changed my code to this:

```
WrappedConnectionJDK7  wc = (WrappedConnectionJDK7 ) conn;
OracleConnection oraconn = (OracleConnection) wc.getUnderlyingConnection();
```

and I added dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.ironjacamar</groupId>
  <artifactId>ironjacamar-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

but still I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7 cannot be cast to 
org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7
```

Comment: Try OracleConnection oraconn = wc.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);

Comment: I'm getting error on this like "WrappedConnectionJDK7  wc = (WrappedConnectionJDK7 ) conn;"

Answer (score 0):

I have had to unwrap similar connections (but not exactly the same wrapper classes) before and have used:

```
OracleConnection oconn;
if ( conn.isWrapperFor( OracleConnection.class ) )
{
  oconn = (OracleConnection) conn.unwrap( OracleConnection.class );
}
else
{
  throw new SQLException( "Not an Oracle Connection" );
}
```

Comment: I'm getting 
java.sql.SQLException: IJ031030: Not a wrapper for: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection

Answer (score 0):

I've added jboss-deployment-structure.xml in EAR/META-INF and it solved the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
    <sub-deployment name="myapp.jar">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" />
            <module name="com.oracle.db" />
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```